# How clean the string from any none unicode \ special characters, html markup, js - leaving pure text and punctuation - in python?

Tags: python, unicode, web-scraping

I've read a lot of similar questions, but didn't find a solution for all the issues I get with my data cleanup.

I have a script which crawls a set of websites and get a certain block of text from the pages body.

Issues I get are things like html markup still in the text, different symbols for quotes for example (not ' but ` or even worse cases), stuff like &amp and so on.

Right now I parse the text through my own cleanup functions but they are not perfect and still miss some cases.

I was wondering is there is a package or common way to cleanup a string from all of these cases and have characters like ` converted to ' and so on?

Comment: give an example

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTMLParser module.

On python 2:
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

```
class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
def __init__(self):
    self.reset()
    self.fed = []
def handle_data(self, d):
    self.fed.append(d)
def get_data(self):
    return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

On python 3:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
def __init__(self):
    self.reset()
    self.strict = False
    self.convert_charrefs= True
    self.fed = []
def handle_data(self, d):
    self.fed.append(d)
def get_data(self):
    return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

Comment: does this strip away html only or also deals with "weird" symbols?
I also think I encounter different charset at times and not sure how to deal with that...

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at [Scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.3/intro/overview.html)?